# Place each element in a Listbox widget of tkinter module into separate row cell

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I have a Listbox defined as:

```
listbox1=tk.Listbox(master=frame_1,listvariable=samples_var)
```

Where samples_var is a tk.StringVar() class that holds a list of, say, samples. 
For example:

```
samples=["A","B","C","D"]
samples_var=tk.StringVar(value=marko.samples)
```

And then I define tk.Listbox using:

```
listbox1=tk.Listbox(master=frame_1,listvariable=samples_var)
```

I place listbox1 on frame_1 widget by invoking grid. I then specify that I want it starting in row=1,column=3 (as other cells to the left and to the top are occupied), and that I want it spanning the number of rows equal to the length of "samples" list. In above example that is 4 (as there are A,B,C,D) in the "samples" list. This should make it so that the ListBox widgets spans exactly len(samples) rows, starting from.

Code:

```
listbox1.grid(row=1,column=3,rowspan=len(samples),sticky="nsew")
```

Is there any way to snap each element of a list to its own row?
 For example:
A would be in row=1,column=3, B would be in row=2, column=3, C would be in row=3, column=3, etc.
I'm doing this to have nice alignment with rest of widgets in columns.

Comment: No, you cannot.

Comment: Can I at least then somehow modify the listbox so that height of elements in a list matches height of rows in columns next to listbox? For example, if all rows in column=2 have height of say, 50, I'd set the height of listbox as number of elements in listbox x 50. For our example, listbox would then be 4 (because it has elements A,B,C,D) x 50 - 200 which is equivalent to 4 rows in column 3?

Comment: `Listbox` height is in lines, not pixels.  You can try `Text` widget instead and ajust `spacing1` and `spacing3` options.  Why don't you just use `Label` widgets instead of `Listbox`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to snap each element of a list to its own row?

No, there is not. Tkinter is simply not designed to work that way. The height of elements in a list is completely independent of the grid that the listbox may be a part of.

You could try some trickery where you compute the height of a row in the listbox based on the result of the listbox's `bbox` command, and then try to coerce the height of each row in your grid to the same size, though it seems like a lot more work than it's worth.